# Connect Trekking Bike Brakes to Road Bike Lever

Tags: brakes, gears, hybrid-bike, brake-levers

A family member will give me his old (high class) trekking bike. I like the bike a lot but would like to swap the steering bar for a road bike one, which I am used to and like a lot.

- Is it possible to simply connect the Deore LX brakes to my 600 Tricolore road bike levers?
- Is it alternatively possible to buy road bike brake/gear levers that can operate the trekking bike brakes *and* gears?

My question is similar to [this one](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12456/will-a-road-brake-lever-work-with-a-v-brake), but I am unsure if the answer applies. Plus, ultimately I'd like to replace the gear lever as well.

Comment: After reading around a bit, maybe a bullhorn with guidonnet brake levers would be easiest.

Comment: Close as I can tell, Deore LX is a V brake, while the Tricolor is a conventional caliper.  These are not compatible due to the difference in cable travel.  In some cases one might replace the V brakes with cantilever brakes to make the Tricolor levers work, but there are a lot of buts.

Comment: Your questionsis also similar to this question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/37418/any-issues-installing-sti-brake-shifter-levers-to-bike-with-direct-pull-v-cantil and perharps the answers will make your option a bit clearer:

Comment: @DanielRHicks That's correct. And the "buts" make it quite difficult, but still the best option. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the cable pull of a road lever to work with a V-Brake by using a [Travel Agent](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/travel-agent-installation-and-adjustment)

Comment: We don't know what type of brakes the OP even has. LX series is older than V brakes, and 600 is even older.

Comment: My googling suggested a Deore LX had at least 2 generations of V-Brake.  Although granted the OP could have something older.  But increased cable pull wouldn't stop the brake working, it would just make it more sensitive to use.

Comment: Check https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/27115/are-road-brakes-designed-not-to-brake-too-much for how V brake levels work with brakes designed for shorter pull

Answer (score 1):

You want to connect **short-pull** levers with **long-pull** brakes. If done directly, this won't work effectively as you won't exert enough force on the brakes to stop you effectively.
More on pull lengths can be found in [What is the actual cable pull of brake levers?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20809/what-is-the-actual-cable-pull-of-brake-levers)

You need some mechanism to increase the pull length, either the one mentioned in the answer to this question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/59105/34697 or some DIY mechanism inspired by [How much cable can I pull with a brake lever in another custom mechanism, and how can I achieve it?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56636/how-much-cable-can-i-pull-with-a-brake-lever-in-another-custom-mechanism-and-ho/56637#56637) - if you trust your DIY skills.

If you want to retain your road brake levers, which are short-pull, and pull-length conversion contraption is not an option, you need to get yourself some short-pull brakes. These can either be **cantilever brakes** (you will make use of the currently available brake bosses) or find suitable (called long-reach) caliper brakes (or their center-pull version).

Both options (changing the brakes or installing the pull-length converter) will allow you to later replace the brake levers with some brifters (road bike brake levers integrated with the derailleur shifters).